# Output the gotten json data from the database

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, web

I read the data from the database as json object. Also took that data to another page, where I want to show that data, but the problem is in showing the data.

Here is my code for showing data: 
Please check the comments in the code!!!

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

            object = JSON.stringify(this.responseText);
            console.log(object);


            console.log(object);
            //console.log(object['data'][0]['title']); ERROR

            object2 = JSON.parse(object)
            console.log(object2);
            //console.log(object2['data'][0]['title']); ERROR
            console.log(object2.title); //here  ENDEFINED




            objectParsed = JSON.parse(
                '{"ID":"1","type":"zima","title":"skijanje","description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,sed diam voluptua.","people":"From 2 to 8","available":"From November to February","price":"From 350 to 500","numTaken":"0"}'
            );

            console.log(objectParsed);
            console.log(objectParsed.title); // here I got the right ouput which is SKIJANJE

            //document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = object.title;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "readTourData.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
```

And here is the data I got from "readTourData" 
[image]

Finally here is the output when I try to show data: 
[image]

The variable object look like this (console.log(object) ) : [image]

The data I got from the db: 
data: [{ID: "1", type: "zima", title: "skijanje",…}]

0
:
{ID: "1", type: "zima", title: "skijanje",…}
ID
:
"1"
available
:
"From November to February"
description
:
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,sed diam voluptua."
numTaken
:
"0"
people
:
"From 2 to 8"
price
:
"From 350 to 500"
title
:
"skijanje"
type
:
"zima"

Console output:

--First console --> console.log(object) :
"\r\n    data: [{\"ID\":\"1\",\"type\":\"zima\",\"title\":\"skijanje\",\"description\":\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,sed diam voluptua.\",\"people\":\"From 2 to 8\",\"available\":\"From November to February\",\"price\":\"From 350 to 500\",\"numTaken\":\"0\"}]\r\n\r\n"

--Second console --> console.log(object2): 
data: [{"ID":"1","type":"zima","title":"skijanje","description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,sed diam voluptua.","people":"From 2 to 8","available":"From November to February","price":"From 350 to 500","numTaken":"0"}]

-- Third console --> console.log(object2.title) : 
undefined

-- Fourth console -- > console.log(objectParsed): 
{ID: "1", type: "zima", title: "skijanje", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,sed diam voluptua.", people: "From 2 to 8", …}
ID
:
"1"
available
:
"From November to February"
description
:
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,sed diam voluptua."
numTaken
:
"0"
people
:
"From 2 to 8"
price
:
"From 350 to 500"
title
:
"skijanje"
type
:
"zima"
**proto**
:
Object

--and last console --> console.log(objectParsed.title):
Skijanje

Comment: As you can see in your image, the data is an array, not an object. Access an array element before trying to access a property like `title`. Also, why are you trying to stringify `responseText`, it's already a string??

Comment: I tried to access array element before getting the title value...but it doesn't work. And a use stringify(this.responseText) because it doesn't work without it. I got this error withour stringify:
 Uncaught ReferenceError: object is not defined
    at XMLHttpRequest.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange

Comment: @AbuMachi Can you please share the code where you try to access array element?

Comment: I'm  trying this ways:
 console.log(object[2]);
console.log(object[2]['title']);
console.log(object[2].title);

But each of them doesn't work

Comment: You log this after `JSON.parse()` or before it? And what is the log output you are getting? Just saying "Doesn't work" won't help us understand the problem.

Comment: after parse...output is undefined

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that there is no `object.title`.

The `object` object appears to be an array.

Each object in the array appears to have a `title` attribute.

So you should be able to access the title of the first object in the array with something like: `object[0].title` or `object[0]['title']`

It is often helpful to print out the object to see all of this nesting with something like

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(object,null,1));
```

This way it would have been more clear that you needed to access the `data` property and what that property looks like.

Comment: I try each of your suggestion, but no one help me solving the problem.
I these error: 
--
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at XMLHttpRequest.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange

Comment: Please update your question to make it clear which `console.log()` your output is from and can you show the code that is producing the "Uncaught TypeError" (don't paste in comments - please update your question).

Comment: It would also be helpful if you pasted the text output from the console.log(), rather than a screen shot.

Comment: I will do it now

Comment: i editted it...and you can see that I remove two row from table...to be easier for testing

Comment: Updated. I have no idea where "data" is coming from, but apparently it isn't part of your object.

Comment: it is only string...I put the object with I output in the console

Comment: So you're showing different code than is generating the output. Trying to figure out which line of your code is generating what output is making it very difficult to help you.